# Слайдер с наложением друг на друга

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как можно реализовать подобный слайдер с неким наложением текущей картинки поверх [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а готовое использовать можно ?

Comment: Да, главное узнать как такое реализовать

Comment: 1) https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/NMKPNV

Comment: устраивает  такая карусель ?

Comment: Большое спасбио

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь готовым сладером, например Slick (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/). Далее найдите класс, который обозначает текущий слайд и выставите ему стиль CSS

```
 position: absolute,
 z-index: 10,
```

В нашем случае нужно добавить правило CSS

```
.slick-current {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: -35px;
    margin-right: -35px;
}
```

А для генерации слайдера используем код:

```
$('.variable-width').slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  centerMode: true,
  variableWidth: true
});
```

Работать будет не слишком плавно, но суть решена.

Comment: Вопрос теперь в другом я ему поставил вместо стрелок доты(точки) и хочу например чтоб слайдер был в середине блока,а точки прижаты в низу блока, как это реализовать можно? пытаюсь через .slider .slick-dots Но тогда сам слайдер выше уезжает и перекрывает другие элементы которые выше. То есть можно ли чтоб сам слайдер на месте остался,а доты ниже передвинуть?

Comment: У класса .slick-dots указано абсолютное позиционирование. Попробуйте изменить параметр "bottom". Сделайте например bottom: 10px;

Comment: Получилось, а как можно ещё сделать чтоб эти .slick-dots не уезжали ещё вниз если у блока стоит 100vh

Comment: Попробуйте к класса  .slick-dots установить margin-top: 50px;

Comment: @Олег ответы какие либо помогли вам в прошлом вашем вопросе ?

Comment: Да большое спасибо, только указал position: relative;
 bottom: -170px; и сработало